# Compress image on the fly before upload with FTP

Tags: android, kotlin

I strugle a lot here, how to upload images with ftp bit first compress it so it's not that big.

I got problem the upload don't accept bytearray, URI, bitmap, i try everything but i still fail to accomplish the task.

Are even possible to upload without making temp dir and saving file there then from there upload it using ftp?

Here is the issue, how to pass that compression to the upload

```
 val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(it.getPath())
                    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream) //compress to 50% of original image quality
                    val byte_arr = stream.toByteArray()

                    publishProgress(it.name, i++, count)
                    _client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
                    _client.upload(File(byte_arr))
```

And here is the full code

```
 override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String): Void? {
    val _client = FTPClient()
    try {
        val sharedPreferences = _context.getSharedPreferences("file_cache", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //create device unique id for for device folder
        var uniqueID = sharedPreferences.getString("UUID", "")
        if(uniqueID == "") {
            with(sharedPreferences.edit()){ // flag that file in local storage
                uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                putString("UUID", uniqueID)
                apply()
            }
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "UUID: " + uniqueID)

        _client.connect(params[1], 21) // Connecting to ftp server
        _client.login(params[2], params[3])
        //_client.enterLocalPassiveMode()
        _client.changeDirectory(params[0])
        try {
            _client.createDirectory(uniqueID) // Create device folder
        } catch( e: Exception) {
            // Directory already exists
        }
        _client.changeDirectory(uniqueID)

        if(_client.isCompressionSupported()){
            _client.setCompressionEnabled(true);
        }

        val dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        val files = dir.walk()
                .filter { it ->  EXTENSIONS.containsMatchIn(it.extension) }
                .filter { it -> !it.absolutePath.contains(".thumbnails", true)}
                .filter { it -> !it.absolutePath.contains(".cache", true)}
                .filter { it -> !it.absolutePath.contains("data", true)}
                .filter { it -> !sharedPreferences.getBoolean(it.absolutePath, false) }

        val count = files.count()
        if(count == 0) return null

        Log.i(TAG, "Found " + count.toString() + " files!")
        var i = 0;
        val cm = _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val activeNetwork = cm.activeNetworkInfo
        val isWiFi = activeNetwork.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI

        if(isWiFi) {
            Log.i(TAG, "On Wifi!")
            files.forEach {
                Log.d(TAG, it.absolutePath)

                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(it.getPath())
                val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream) //compress to 50% of original image quality
                val byte_arr = stream.toByteArray()

                publishProgress(it.name, i++, count)
                _client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
                _client.upload(File(byte_arr))
                with(sharedPreferences.edit()){ // flag that file in local storage
                    putBoolean(it.absolutePath, true)
                    apply()
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No WiFi... Bye....")
        }
        _client.logout()
        _client.disconnect(true)
    } catch (e: FTPException) {
        Log.d("FTP", e.toString())
        return null
    } catch (e: SocketException) {
        Log.d("SOCKET", e.toString())
        return null
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        try { // try to logout and disconnect
            _client.logout()
            _client.disconnect(true)
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            return null
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: What king of files do you want to upload? JPG's ? No need to compress.

Comment: Why messing aroud wit Bitmap if you want to upload a file? Wrong approach.

Comment: If you have to use FTP, then yes, you need to write the file to a temp folder in order to have a file path that you can pass to the FTP Client so the client can upload the file via FTP.  This is usually done by creating an API that takes a string parameter, say 'encodedData', and you convert your bitmap's byteArray into a base64 encoded string, then you pass that string to the API.  The API converts the encoded string back to whatever format required for storage on the server.  No need to use FTP at all.